# Discordbot with Javascript not reacting

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

im currently learning to code discordbots with node.js.  For some reason the bot goes online but dont react to the commands ive coded. To test reasons ive even took the solution from a tutorial but still the same problem. Does anybody know a solution?

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = '-';
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('BOT ist online');
});

client.on('Message', (message) => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!');}
    else if(command == 'youtube'){
        message.channel.send('TEST');}
    });
client.login('Here goes the token');
```

Comment: Is the `client.on('Message' ...` code being triggered at all? What's the output when running `console.log(args)` and `console.log(command)`?

Comment: Which discord.js version are you using @mdmx

Comment: As @BackTrack said below, it looks like you’re using a capital M in Message when you should be using a lowercase. If there’s more to it than that I’ll try my best to help. 

That just seemed like the most obvious thing to try to change first. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a small fix so I would just comment if I could but I’m not able to yet.

Where you’re doing:

```js
client.on('Message', …)
```

It should be a lowercase "m" on message like this:

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
     msg.reply('Pong!');
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is solved, the reason was to make the m lowercase. Thank you all guys :)